# Is Darth Vader a pig or a bird?

Tags: angry-birds-star-wars

Now that *Angry Birds Star Wars* is out in all of its glory, I just have to know: Is the Darth Vader character supposed to be a pig or a bird?  He looks like a pig, but I haven't completed the game with all of its bonuses and haven't seen it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @fbueckert Does it matter?  [Since when do we only ask questions with an impact on the gameplay](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20479/how-much-in-game-time-has-passed-between-portal-1-and-2)?

Comment: [FAQ]: `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.`

Comment: [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) `If your question generally covers things such as... Plot and characters in games …then you are in the right place to ask your question!` If this is not a question about plot/character, feel free to close/delete it.

Comment: I honestly don't see why this question should be closed. It's a question about the plot. Allowing these types of questions does not harm the site as long as they don't become the majority. [Further reading](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: Voting to re-open. This question is about an in-game character which, a mmdanziger already pointed out, is on-topic as outlined in our [FAQ].

Comment: I'm sorry you've gotten mixed signals from some of the minority, but your question did not need—and is actually harmed by—a long justification for some sort of underlying meaning behind a mobile game. Questions answered by facts = okay, speculation and reading between the lines = generally not okay.

Comment: All of the above having been said, I won't vote to close this question. I will however downvote it. It's dumb, shows poor research effort, and is unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In a <del>shocking</del> twist, Lard Vader is unveiled to be:
[image: The mask removed...]
[image: And Lard Vader has embraced his bird roots once again]

A bird in a pig mask!

Comment: Is the "Lard Vader" some inside joke I don't get, or should it be "L**o**rd" instead?

Comment: "According to the Angry Birds Star Wars Character Encyclopedia, his official name is Lard Vader." -- http://angrybirds.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Characters

Answer (score 12):

Birds are the Light Side and the Rebel Alliance, pigs are the Dark Side and the Empire. As such, Darth Vader is a pig-equivalent. Behold the trailer:

At 31 seconds in, the gameplay footage clearly demonstrates Darth Vader's pig-itude.

Additionally, at 23 seconds in, this adorable "unboxing" video of Hasbro's Angry Birds Star Wars toys shows the packaging labels Darth Vader as "Darth Vader Pig":

Moreover, the game only includes levels that feature:

- Tatooine
- The first Death Star encounter
- Hoth (eventually via a free update)
- Dagobah (via in-app purchase)

Meaning it stops around halfway though the plot to *The Empire Strikes Back*. If there is an eventual redemption for the Darth Vader pig or a twist ending regarding his true nature, it's not in this game, or at the very least, not in this game *yet*.